# How to find count of a single column?

Tags: r

I have single column table and i need to find out count of it

```
status
average
good
bad
need to improve
good
bad 
average
```

Output should be like this

```
Good 2
average 2
bad 2
need to improve 1
```

How to do this?

Comment: `table(status)`.

Comment: Do **not** post images! Why have you edited the question?

Answer (score 0):

For count of rows by unique values using data.table:

```
myframe = data.table(myframe)
myFrame[,.N, by = myColumn]
```